# How to get shared computers' IP addresses in OS X 10.7?

Tags: macos, networking, bonjour

I have list of computers on my "Shared" sidebar, however I don't have their IP addresses.

My router has their IP addresses, however there is no computer-name <> IP address mapping.

How do I find the mapping of computer-name <> IP address?

Answer (score 35):

You can use a tool like [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) or `dns-sd(1)` to browse services, find the hosts publishing those services, and find the IP addresses of those hosts.

With `dns-sd`, it might go something like this:

1. Find hosts sharing files via the Apple Filing Protocol (AFP):

   ```
   dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp local
   ```

   This will give you a list of AFP file services on your local network. You'll have to `Ctrl-C` out of `dns-sd` to get back to the shell prompt.
2. After picking the name of an AFP service from the list, you can find out the `.local` hostname of the host providing that service like this:

   ```
   dns-sd -L MyOtherMac _afpovertcp._tcp local
   ```

   Again, `Ctrl-C` out of it after you get your answer.
3. Resolve the "hostname.local" style mDNS host name to a set of IP addresses:

   ```
   dns-sd -G v4v6 MyOtherMac.local
   ```

   Again, `Ctrl-C` out of it after you get your answer.

Comment: thanks. what about finding windows/netbios mapping ?

Comment: Sorry I am very bad in regular expression.. can you give me some hints to do this with a script and repeat it for each computer on my network?

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat

Open terminal

```
% netstat -a | grep afp
```