# How to get IP address of all users on a network on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, ip, bonjour

There is [a similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/443514/how-to-get-shared-computers-ip-addresses-in-os-x-10-7), but it doesn’t answer some of my questions.

The biggest problem is it says to fill in “MyOtherMac” with the name of the other computer found in the first step. The only unique names in the list were the instance names, which have spaces and colons, which are not accepted by the common specified.

It also doesn’t specify how to find computers that are not Macs on your network.

So my question is either: How to execute the answer in the previous question or how to get IP address of all users on a network on Mac OS X?

Comment: Did you try to wrap your computer name in single quotation marks, e.g. `dns-sd -G v4v6 'My Other Mac.local'`?

Answer (score 8):

Open the terminal, 
Command + T
Type:

```
arp -na
```

then on each of the IP addresses run

```
dig [IP address from first command]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using  IP scanner on my mac to determine all the other computers / devices IP and Mac address. Please note that this is a shareware program.

Also, If you have an apple device (iPhone, iPad) connected to the network you can use the "Fing" app (can be downloaded from the app store) which can give you the name, IP address, Mac address and the vendor of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your router’s web interface—usually by putting your “Default Gateway” in your web browser—then there should be a status tab or something along those lines. In that menu there should be a list of all devices connected to your network.